# Compiler warning about potentially uninitialized variable

Tags: c, gcc, error-handling, gcc-warning

Consider the following pseudo code, which employs the typical error handling tactics with an error code variable:

(*Edit1*: I have added another use-case when the uninit var warnings appear. And no, this pseudo code, though is compilable doesn't actually trigger the GCC warning (v4.9.2). But the real (much larger) code which does is in spirit identical to this pseudo code.)

```
int func1()
{
    int err;
    int a;
    int b;  // *Edit1*

    err = func2( &a ); // init 'a' or fail with 'err'
    if (!err)
    {
        b = 1; // *Edit1*
    }

    if (!err)
    {
        // use variable 'a'
        // here compiler migth produce warning that 'a' might be uninitialized
    }

    if (!err) // *Edit1*
    {
        // use variable 'b'
        // here compiler might produce warning that 'b' might be uninitialized
    }

    return err;
}
```

The GCC would produce a warning that variable 'a' might be potentially uninitialized.

Typical solution is to just add (for example) `a = 0;` at the beginning of the function. But I'm looking for something more generic/elegant. (Compiler fails to optimize away the redundant initializations. Not every variable has a sensible default value.)

My question is: Are there any compiler features which might allow to tell compiler that `func1()` does initializes the `a` if `err` is not set? Or any other method to achieve that with the error handling tactics?

P.S. Considering that this type of error handling is so commonplace, I'm confused that I failed to find ways to make a warning-free code without unnecessary assignments.

Comment: Just asking, why do you have two `if (!err)` conditions?

Comment: I agree that this is extremely annoying,  It's obvious to me that 'a' has a valid address, it's not being dereferenced and the function is surely going to load 'a'.   Not sure how to tell the compiler that, and I want to know how too:(

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I just wanted to highlight and exemplify that usually there are multiple `if (!err)` blocks in the function. Additionally, I also wanted to make clear that the block where `a` becomes initialized normally is not the same where `a` is used.

Comment: Eh? GCC will never produce a warning about `a` being uninitialized in your example unless it inlines `func2` and knows that it wasn't actually initialized. There are complex edge cases where GCC gets confused, but this is definitely not even close to being one.

Comment: Such warnings are false positives, that is: they are tool bugs. Just disable the buggy warning.

Comment: I don't get this warning either. Tried to get it with flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: 10-20 years ago false positives for uninitialized variables were indeed a problem with GCC, today you have to write some pretty convoluted code to trigger them. Majority of those warnings are actual proper bugs in your code and it's worth the occasional unnecessary initialization of a variable to cover them up to keep the warning enabled to catch real bugs.

Comment: Can't confirm. No warning with `extern int func2(int *arg);`, even if using `a` later; `gcc -c foo.c -Wall -Werror -Wuninitialized` 5.2.1-22ubuntu2

Comment: Actually I didn't manage to get a warning **even with `static inline`, and `-O3`**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Same here with static inline. That might actually be a GCC bug that it doesn't report that as uninitialized. The last thing I can think of is that func2() is actually a macro.

Comment: Actually even `printf("%p", &a);` made the warning go away, so it seems that in GCC 5.2.1 the expectation is that any `int` var whose address is taken and passed to *any function at all* is initialized by that function; even if the compiler later could know that this wasn't the case.

Comment: I'm sorry, but yes, the pseudo code doesn't trigger the warning when compiled. The pseudo code is only intended as a demo, not a real code with a problem.

Comment: @Dummy00001: So you expect help diagnosing the cause of a problem we can't reproduce? Seems legit.

Comment: So, the pseudocode does not produce the warning you are asking about.   Can you provide an actual (small!) example that does?   If you don't, nobody can help you.

Comment: I think, minimized compilable example with such warning will be good idea. Particularly, it will be useful to figure out possible optimizer bugs. Now even your edited code cease to reproduce anything.

Comment: I'm not interested in a "fix" for a particular piece of code - I'm capable of doing it myself. As I have expressed the notion in the question: I'm interested in compiler features/methods/tactics one can use to deal with such warnings with this particular error handling. If you are not familiar with that type of the error handling, then please simply move on.

Comment: I feel the description of this issue is clear, no matter whether the "pseudo"-code allows to reproduce it or not.

Comment: initializing the variables IS the elegant solution.

Comment: @alk sure, but users have been wast.. spending time trying to reproduce it with the code given.

Comment: @MartinJames: I agree, that the OP should have done better by initially mentioning this fact, this code is pseudo.

Comment: OMG, the "pseudo code" stood there from the very beginning of the existence of this question. Reading fail.

Comment: I forgot to add to my last comment "*... and does _not_ produce the warning as mentioned.*"

Answer (score -3):

All non static variables prior to defining are undeclared, unless they have defined default constructor. Most basic types are considered primitives and may be inherited from C and follows C's architecture - in that case compiler will determine size, and will allocate this size on stack, nothing more, nothing less - underlying memory is random - or per se - undefined.

if static, **declared** variable is initialized to zero if not defined
otherwise.

all non static variables are left to whatever was in memory segment before claiming it - this can potentially lead to **undefined behaviour** and in extreme cases - information leaks.Also if using heap memory - its preferable to call calloc instead of malloc in C, in C++ you really make yourself sure that there is default constructor and its doing some defaulting after being called.

What you are trying to accomplish is generic compiler functionality and its created to decect potential misuse of uninitialized variables, for example:
`for (int a; i<0; a++)` wchich are potentially dangerous

Notice that compiler describes source file as translation unit - it does not know or care about other source files - this is linker jobs to produce usable binary file from compiled chunks. You can notify compiler (GNU) that you want or do some assumptions on function you are writting, but AFAIK there is notthing to suit your needs [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)

there is one elegant solution to all such problems and it is either default constructor in C++ or in C either basic initialization or calloc zeroing.

If it annoys you, add `-w` to gcc/g++;

example i did:

```
int err = 0;
int a   = 0;
int b   = 0;

err = func2( &a ); // no warnings
if (!err) b = 1;
if (!err) err = stuff(a);
if (!err) err = stuff(b)

return err;
```

If its possible, revert function to take `err` as param, and produce `a` as out. If its impossible (lib?) make wrapper. If you are good with uninitialized parameter, you should be good with calloced parameter, and its fixing whatever problem you may ever have. This is good practice in, for example, microchips or linux kernelspace.

```
somecomplextype * x = (somecomplextype) calloc (1, sizeof(somecomplextype));
if (!x) exit(1);
```

Comment: You did read the full question and its comments, didn't you?

Comment: indeed, i forgot something (edit)

Comment: one more thing i remembered - try to google around about gcc/g++ translations units - if function you are unsing is in another translation unit compiler may fail to detect that function is mutating parameters and give you warning. also this is not answer but may be interesting to you
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.5/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: "My young padawan" - is that really necessary?  It seems rude and condescending.

Comment: A downvote, for (1st) failure to read the question, and (2nd) arrogance.

Comment: read comment before downvoting, i explained all there is to solve your problem. There is no mighty compiler settings to overstep translation unit becouse compiler (1st) dont know what other functions do, (2nd) dont care about other units while compiling. Either put them in one file or initialize before usage.

Comment: You failed to understand the problem. Please do not pretend to solve it. You wrote your answer with the (wrong and arrogant) assumption that I can't read compiler documentation and I lack experience. Just because you do not know the answer doesn't mean there isn't one.